# How often is [frequency] useful?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

We have 51 questions tagged [frequency](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/frequency). This seems like an extremely general, cross-cutting concept that isn't useful as a tag. However, *most* questions tagged [frequency](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/frequency) are questions about CPU frequency. The tag has no tag wiki.

We also have a [cpufreq](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/cpufreq) tag. Some questions currently have both tags. It seems to me that [cpufreq](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/cpufreq) could (and thus far *has been*) used to cover the entire concept of CPU frequency, though *in theory* it is more specific than that. Its [tag wiki excerpt](https://askubuntu.com/tags/cpufreq/info) currently says:

> CPU Frequency, or CPU Frequency Scaling. This is implemented in the Linux kernel, and in versions since 3.4 use an ondemand governor by default, which saves power by using as much as is needed.

A couple [frequency](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/frequency) questions are about CPU frequency but use the tag in a broader way, or are about something similar to but not the same as CPU frequency:

- [Setting intel GPU limits in Ubuntu 17.04 no longer works](https://askubuntu.com/questions/930372/setting-intel-gpu-limits-in-ubuntu-17-04-no-longer-works) is about CPU frequency but also *GPU* frequency.
- [How can I change the frequency of the RAM, and also know its value from Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216542/how-can-i-change-the-frequency-of-the-ram-and-also-know-its-value-from-ubuntu) is about RAM frequency.

A significant minority of [frequency](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/frequency) questions aren't about CPU frequency or anything related to it:

- [Can Simon's voice recognition understand frequency instead of words?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1113866/can-simons-voice-recognition-understand-frequency-instead-of-words) and [Filter high-pitched sound on live audio](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073378/filter-high-pitched-sound-on-live-audio) are about pitch.
- [Finding the frequency of CAN (controller area network) send and receive messages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/945657/finding-the-frequency-of-can-controller-area-network-send-and-receive-messages) is about [CAN](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/api-reference/peripherals/can.html#basic-can-concepts).
- [Ubuntu phone (Aquarius 4.5) change of UMTS frequency](https://askubuntu.com/questions/754640/ubuntu-phone-aquarius-4-5-change-of-umts-frequency) is about [UMTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UMTS) bands (for cellular phones).
- [Wifi connection deauthenticated by router](https://askubuntu.com/questions/578174/wifi-connection-deauthenticated-by-router) and [How to find which WiFi frequencies are being used the most near by?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55740/how-to-find-which-wifi-frequencies-are-being-used-the-most-near-by) are about Wi-Fi.
- [Change Logitech Unifying Reciever Frequency Band?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463858/change-logitech-unifying-reciever-frequency-band) is about a wireless mouse (and interference from Wi-Fi).
- [Can I sync a folder once a day rather than immediately](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289277/can-i-sync-a-folder-once-a-day-rather-than-immediately) is about how often a backup is performed.
- [How to check current monitor frequency?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210074/how-to-check-current-monitor-frequency), [cannot do anything after booting ubuntu 12.04 lts  , problem with resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164103/cannot-do-anything-after-booting-ubuntu-12-04-lts-problem-with-resolution), and [Frequency out of range ATI HD 4670](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67681/frequency-out-of-range-ati-hd-4670) are about monitors (or graphics cards).

What should we do with the [frequency](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/frequency) tag? Should we keep it? If so, should it retain is currently very general meaning? Should we remove it from questions that aren't about CPU frequency and make it a synonym of [cpufreq](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/cpufreq)? Or should we edit it out of the posts that currently have it, replacing it with [cpufreq](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/cpufreq) or other tags where applicable?

My inclination is to think it's fine to [cpufreq](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/cpufreq) on any post about CPU frequency, and that the [frequency](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/frequency) tag need not exist. But I'm not sure.

Comment: +1 for your last paragraph

Comment: I'd prefer all tags to be pretty general and using combinations of those to add specific meaning. For example, one could have both `frequency` and `cpu` if they mean CPU frequency. Or they could have `ram` `overclock` `frequency` for some another question.

Comment: I think that `cpufreq` is supposed to refer to frequency *scaling* and not just cpu frequency. https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/admin-guide/pm/cpufreq.html#cpu-performance-scaling-in-linux